# ogr2ogr .osm.pbf speed up clip

Tags: python, shapefile, openstreetmap, ogr2ogr, clip

At the moment I am clipping osm.pbf files. From the osm file, I only want to extract the buildings. The outcome should be shapefile with all the buildings within a nuts2 area.

The following code works:

```
pbf = 'A://CORINE//OSM//%s-latest.osm.pbf' % (country)
nuts_wgs = "A:\\CORINE\\%s\\NUTS2_SHAPE\\%s_wgs.shp" % (country,nuts)
wgs = 'A://CORINE//%s//NUTS2_BUILDING//%s_buildings_wgs.shp' % (country,nuts)

os.system('ogr2ogr -progress -f "ESRI shapefile" ' + wgs + ' ' + pbf + ' -clipsrc ' + nuts_wgs + ' -sql "select building from multipolygons where building is not null" -nlt POLYGON -skipfailures')
```

But this code is relative slow. I have found some documentation about clipsrcsql and clipsrclayer. If I add one of those to the code, it will be much faster (approx. 6 times faster), but a clip to the nuts2 file does not occur anymore (it simply gives all the buildings of the country as an output).

Does anyone have an idea either on:

1) how clipsrcsql or clipsrclayer work (documentation is very limited)?

2) how to improve the speed of the calculation in general. Especially for areas with many buildings (e.g. Netherlands, France, Germany), a speed improvement is required?

Comment: Data in osm.pbf is not indexed by attributes nor spatially. I fear you can't get any dramatic improvement in the speed. I hope I am wrong and someone corrects me.

Comment: I merged the extract and clip because It seemed it became quicker. Would it be possible to have more speed gains when clipping the building data shapefile seperately?

Comment: Try it. Clipping shapefile with GDAL is fast but you must create first the spatial index (.qix).

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question per question.